# Issues with deploying smart contract using Sepolia test net

Tags: contract-deployment, sepolia

I am having issues deploying my smart contract in hardhat using the sepolia test net. I keep getting the "Network sepolia doesnt exist" error as well as "Option moduleresolution must be set next to NodeNext" error when I switch over to typescript( I would rather use javaScript).
Here is my configuration file with my deploy script below it. Please help as I am very frustrated as to what is going wrong( This is my first project so I am anxious haha).

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

           /** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */

           const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
           require("dotenv").config();
           require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers");
           import("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers");
           import("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers");

           module.exports = {
              solidity: {
               compilers: [
               {
             version: "0.5.9",
             },
            {
             version: "0.8.0",
            },
           {
          version: "0.8.19",
           },
          {
          version: "0.8.9",
          },
          {
          version: "0.8.21",
          },
          ],

           defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
             networks: {
             hardhat: {},
             sepolia: {
                 url: API_URL,
                 accounts: ["0x${PRIVATE_KEY}"],
                 chainId: 11155111,
                },
               },
              },
            };
```

**my deploy script named SpiderVerseDeploy.js**

```
           import { ethers } from "hardhat";
           import "hardhat/console.sol";

           async function main() {
             const SpiderVerse = await ethers.getContractFactory("SpiderVerse");
             const spiderVerse = await SpiderVerse.deploy("SpiderVerse");

             await spiderVerse.deployed();

              console.log("Contract deployed to address:", spiderVerse.address);
             }

              main();
              main().catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
              process.exitCode = 1;
            });
```

I have my private information stored as variables in a .env file and set up my sepolia testnet account in my metamask wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of basic things I would say to try:

1. `accounts : [PRIVATE_KEY]` instead of `accounts: ["0x${PRIVATE_KEY}"]`.
2. Remove chainId, it's not needed.
3. make sure you are running the command right. i.e.

`npx hardhat run ./scripts/SpiderVerseDeploy.js --network sepolia`

Comment: hello. thank you for responding. It is still telling me that the sepolia network doesnt exist. i really have no clue as to why its doing this. I believe I have all the packages installed so idk. It is very annoying.

Comment: This is strange, do you have a github repo for the same project, I can try on my machine and check what's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Basically, Hardhat recently made the little few changes in the deployment script. You have to change them in your code let me show you**

**update the hardhat.config.js file**

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify");

require('dotenv').config();

const {PRIVATE_KEY, URL, APIKEY } = process.env;

  module.exports = {
     solidity: "0.8.19",
     defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
     networks: {
        hardhat: {},
      
       sepolia: {
          url: URL,                          //Infura/Alchemy RPC-URL for sepolia
          accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],    //Metamask Private Key
        },

     },

     etherscan: {
      apiKey: APIKEY,
    },
  }
```

**Update the deploy.js File**

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

  const lock = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Lock");

  await lock.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(`contract is deployed to ${lock.target}`);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Comment: Ok I see. I will give it a shot. Also when I store my information for my private key how would I store it in the process.env file? What would be the syntax is what I mean? As in would I have to put [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`] before my key?

Comment: in the .env file just copy the private key from your wallet and paste it as it is